# how can i pass a value to a component on a windows application form from another using visual c in visual studio2010

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010

Please can any one help me on this? I'm working on a project and i've been trying to pass a value(string) to be displayed on a label at runtime, the label is in a form, but i want my codes to be on a different form. Using visual c++   in visual studio 2010. Thanks. I already tried adding the component i.e the label to the second form:

```
this->Controls->Add(sform->usernamelabel);
this->usernamelabel->Text=activeuser;
```

and then tried to pass the value to the label but that didnt work out as it gave me an error notice `Error  1   error C2039: 'usernamelabel' : is not a member of 'secproj::Form1'  c:\users\rasheed .a.o\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\secproj\secproj\Form1.h 204 1   secproj.`

Comment: Try to create a method on sform to be called from second form...

Comment: `usernamelabel` is probably not declared `public` in `sform`.